# Reward Probability on Biased Coin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I tried so hard to figure out this question, but I couldn't. I thought ((1/7)^3)^2

I would appreciate your help.

```
You and your friend play a game with a significantly biased coin where the
probability of a head is 
1/7. The coin will be flipped 3 times.​ Let's model the total number of heads
with X ​(you can use a known random variable for X​) and your reward points
after the game will be R = X^2.
```

Then, your expected reward after the game R will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply you can use a binomial $B(3;1/7)$ and you have to calculate

$$E(X^2)=V(X)+E^2(X)=3\times \frac{1}{7}\times\frac{6}{7}+\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The expectation is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^3 k^2\binom3k\left(\frac17\right)^k\left(\frac67\right)^{3-k}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it. :) @user